# Exponents in LaTeX without Math Mode

Tags: latex

I was wondering if there was a way to write exponents in LaTeX without Math Mode?

Math Mode centers the text in the middle of the paper, which is inconvenient for the paper I am trying to write.

Comment: You can enclose inline formulas in a single `$`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\textsuperscript{...}` outside of math mode to do this. For example:

`n\textsuperscript{2}` for n-squared,

`n\textsuperscript{th}` for n-th.

My understanding is that both `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript` used to be part of the [`fixltx2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) package until 2015 when they and some other commands were added directly into LaTeX so no package was needed.

Comment: `\textsuperscript` has been in the kernel since 1995. `fixltx2e` added `\textsubscript` in 2005; that command got moved in to the latex kernel at the end of 2014.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to use `$....$`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, ngerman, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
This is a blind text trying to write exponents in a textline. $a^{2}$  This is a blind text trying to write exponents in a textline.

$a^{2}$
\end{document}
```

The first part of the code gives you an exponent during textflow. The second part creates an exponent on the left.